# How does Photoshop show multi-layer in Normal Blend Mode?

Tags: photoshop, formula, blend, mode

I'm trying to understand how the normal blend mode works in photoshop.
http://www.pegtop.net/delphi/articles/blendmodes/normal.htm
As the webpage says,it just shows the color of the layer above.But when I copy the same layer and show them together,the color seems darker than just show one layer.And when I add more,the color remains at a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

The normal blend mode shows the color of the topmost fully opaque layer, for transparent layers it will add from top down until fully opaque is reached.

This means that if you have a fully opaque red element over any, for example, blue element, the color red will be displayed. If you have a red element that's 50% transparent over a blue element, the color pink will be displayed.

If you have one black element that is 50% transparent it will appear as a medium gray, if you duplicate the layer, the two elements on top of each other will add up to display a complete black.